# How do I move a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

I have a wordpress.org site that I have built with a custom theme. I now want to move an existing blog from wordpress.com to the new .org site to sit as a blog section on the site. Is this possible and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's proosible to migrate the blog from .com to .org , just export the all data from .com site via Tools -> Export and import them via wordpress importer or you can use [WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/) command line method.

Here you need to use the command to import faster.

```
wp import example.wordpress.2016-06-21.xml --authors=create --skip=image_resize
```